# How to check if bit is set in byte java

Tags: android

I have a byte, and I have a function that checks whether the n-th bit index of the byte is a 1 or a 0. The function returns true if the bit is a 1 and false if the bit is a 0.

How I do, Thank.

Answer (score 5):

You need to *and* your value with a binary mask where the bit to test is set to 1:

```
boolean test(int value) {
     return (value & (1<<N)) != 0;
}
```

Here `1<<N` constructs such a mask where bit N is set to 1, and the others are set to 0. Otherwise you can hand-craft your mask.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do what you need. First parameter is byte where you wants to check presence of bit. Second parameter is a position of bit you wants to check.

```
public static boolean isBitSetInByte(byte Byte, int position) {
    return ((Byte << (~position & 31)) < 0);
}
```

For example:

```
boolean isBitEightSet = isBitSetInByte((byte) 0xF4, 8);
```

This will return true because bit 8 is set in byte F4.